# How to point a domain to a WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress page with this structure `http://mywebsite.com/page`

I want my `http://otherdomain.com` to point to `http://mywebsite.com/page` but the user should see the `http://otherdomain.com` domain at his browser? The A record in my DNS points `http://otherdomain.com` and `http://mywebsite.com` to the same IP.

How to achieve this goal? I though about VirtualHosts but since the folder /page doesn't really exist in the server but is created dynamically by WordPress via .htaccess

How can I point my domain to the WordPress page?

After Roel answer I edited my htaccess.conf file at the WordPress Bitnami installation to add this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain\.com.br$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.otherdomain.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://mywebsite.com.br/page/ [L,R=301]
```

The code is being called, because it adds the `www` to the main URL, but it's not working, because it displays contents from `mywebsite.com.br` and not from `mywebsite.com.br/page`.

I tried another code which is

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} otherdomain\.com.br [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com.br/page/$1 [L]
```

In  this case, it display the contents from `http://mywebsite.com.br/page`however it changes my URL `http://mywebsite.com.br/page` as well which is not what I'm looking for, since I want to keep the user's browser at `http://otherdomain.com.br`

Comment: Do `mywebsite.com` and `otherdomain.com` share the same document root ?

Comment: I pointed `otherdomain.com` to the same CNAME alias that `mywebsite.com` is pointed

Comment: You mean that if you go to either `otherdomain.com` or `mywebsite.com` you'll get the same page content ?

Comment: No. 

I want that if I go to `otherdomain.com` I get the contents from `mywebsite.com/page/` without updating the URL. However, `/page/` isn't a folder in the server but a WordPress pretty URL

Comment: Ok that was not my question. I meant `now` if you go to `otherdomain.com` do you have the same content as `mywebsite.com` ?

Comment: Yes, that happens with Roel's answer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SEO and duplicate content issues aside:

WordPress is aware of the domain it is supposed to be answering to in the database.  The WordPress site itself will *also* redirect based on the domain name set in the WordPress dashboard (under "Settings" => "General").

This isn't going to work well using htaccess.  You're actually going to want the domain name `http://otherdomain.com` to point to the server where `mywebsite.com` lives (not using a forward, but modifying the A record in your DNS).  The reason is that when you rewrite the domain name, the WordPress site is also going to look for css and js files at that domain (looking for them at `otherdomain.com`).  If you have the domain pointed to the WordPress server, this will work properly.

In order to cause WordPress to allow "answering" to multiple domains, you need to modify the code in your WordPress installation so that it will not rewrite the url to `http://mywebsite.com`.  To do this, add the below PHP code to your WordPress theme's function.php file:

What you need to do is to add filter(s) to the relevant hooks that return the site URL, so you can modify it as you see fit:

```
// This will allow you to modify the site url that is stored in the db when it is requested by WP
add_filter('option_siteurl', 'my_custom_filter_siteurl', 1);

// This will allow you to modify the home page url that is stored in the db when it is requested by WP
add_filter('option_home', 'my_custom_filter_home', 1);

// Modify the site url that WP gets from the database if appropriate
function my_custom_filter_siteurl( $url_from_settings ) {
    // Call our function to find out if this is a legit domain or not
    $current_domain = my_custom_is_domain_valid();
    // If so, use it
    if ( $current_domain ) {
        return "http://{$current_domain}";
        // Otherwise, use the default url from settings
    } else {
        return $url_from_settings;
    }
}

// Modify the home page url that WP gets from the database if appropriate
function my_custom_filter_home( $home_from_settings ) {
    // Call our function to find out if this is a legit domain or not
    $current_domain = my_custom_is_domain_valid();
    // If so, use it
    if ( $current_domain ) {
        $base_url = "http://{$current_domain}";
        // Modify / remove this as appropriate.  Could be simply return $base_url;
        return $base_url . "/home-page";
    // Otherwise, use the default url from settings
    } else {
        return $home_from_settings;
    }
}

// Utility function to determine URL and whether valid or not
function my_custom_is_domain_valid() {
    // Create a whitelist of valid domains you want to answer to
    $valid = array(
        'otherdomain.com',
        'mywebsite.com.br',
    );

    // Get the current domain name
    $current_server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    // If it's a whitelisted domain, return the domain
    if ( in_array( $current_server, $valid ) ) {
        return $current_server;
    }

    // Otherwise return false so we can use the default set in the DB
    return FALSE;
}
```

Adding the following filters and functions will cause the desired page to appear as the home page, without the `/page` in the URL:

```
// This will allow you to modify if a page should be shown on the home page
add_filter('option_show_on_front', 'my_custom_show_on_front');

// This will allow you to modify WHICH page should be shown on the home page
add_filter('option_page_on_front', 'my_custom_page_on_front');

// Modify if a page should be shown on the home page
function my_custom_show_on_front( $default_value ) {
    // We only want to do this on specific domain
    $is_other_domain = my_custom_is_other_domain();
    // Ensure it's the domain we want to show the specific page for
    if ( $is_other_domain ) {
        return 'page';
        // Otherwise, use the default setting
    } else {
        return $default_value;
    }
}

// Modify WHICH should be shown on the home page
function my_custom_page_on_front( $default_value ) {
    // We only want to do this on specific domain
    $is_other_domain = my_custom_is_other_domain();
    // Ensure it's the domain we want to show the specific page for
    if ( $is_other_domain ) {
        // If it's the proper domain, set a specific page to show
        // Alter the number below to be the ID of the page you want to show
        return 5;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, use the default setting
        return $default_value;
    }
}

// Utility function to easily determine if the current domain is the "other" domain
function my_custom_is_other_domain() {
    $current_domain = my_custom_is_domain_valid();

    return ($current_domain == 'otherdomain.com') ? $current_domain : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work to integrate WordPress with the multiple domains. However, it didn't solve my issue which is I want that when the user go to `otherdomain.com` it serves the content from `mywebsite.com.br/page` without adding `/page` into the URL

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos - that piece is not going to be solve-able unless you set `mywebsite.com.br/page` to be your front page in WordPress (under "Settings" => "Reading", the top setting is "Front Page Displays".  Change it to "A Static Page", and select the `/page` page.

Comment: But it should be the front-page only if I get there from `otherdomain.com`. If I get there from `mywebsite.com.br`, the front-page should be other. Is this possible?

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos - let me see if I can find a filter on that for you.  Give me a few hours.

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos - I have updated the answer to include two new filters, and three new functions.  These filters / functions will cause the home page to display the desired page, without the `/page` in the url.  Please review and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mywebsite.com/page [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried to do this at the .htaccess page from WordPress installation folder and it didn't work out. 

I edited the question with my code now

Comment: You should add this to the wordpress install but to the virtualhost or .htaccess of the virtualhost

Comment: I am at Bitnami and the right path was `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf`. The code is now called, but it's not working. 

It adds `www` to the otherdomain.com when I type but do not display the contents from mywebsite.com/page, only mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be redirecting the user to mywebsite.com with [L,R=301], rather, you should use the P flag which allows you to ask mod_rewrite to act as a **proxy** for the domain otherdomain.com. something like this,

```
RewriteRule /(.*) http://mywebsite.com/page/$1 [P]
```

make sure to change the css files too to the following,

```
RewriteRule /css/(.*) http://mywebsite.com/css/$1 [P]
```

which will allow all your otherwebsite.com css to become mywebsite.com css and display as otherwebsite.com/css rather than mywebsite.com/page/css

but in order to do this, you need to have mod_proxy loaded and enabled. Do however note that this will reduce performance compared to using mod_proxy directly, as it doesn't handle persistent connections or connection pooling.

Comment: The problem is that `mywebsite.com/page` is not a real folder in the server. It's not like if I had like /var/www/page. It's a WordPress pretty URL self-generated page, so I believe that the CSS part doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. It may not work, but it will give you some idea on where to find the solution.

Basically you need to use `an external redirect` from `otherdomain` to `mywebsite` and then `an internal redirect` from `mywebsite` to `otherdomain`. But it may cause a loop so you need to use some condition to escape it.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain\.com.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com.br/page/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://otherdomain.com.br [E=FINISH:1]
```