# Why is my website not showing up, although the A record is correct?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have been following this answer to point to a certain article/post of my WordPress site with a custom domain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32772582/963830. So I added some functions to the `functions.php`, registered a new domain and created a new A record pointing to the same IP as the main domain.

The A record seems to work:

```
PING neutroninterferometry.com (81.19.145.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www41.world4you.com (81.19.145.61): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=6.32 ms
```

and

```
PING matter-wave-interferometry.org (81.19.145.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www41.world4you.com (81.19.145.61): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=8.36 ms
```

The primary domain works, but not the new one http://matter-wave-interferometry.org. Why?

Then I checked the name servers, but they are all the same, so that should be correct too.

There is something I don't understand yet, but we have a tight schedule right now, and therefore I am turning to you. I guess that the domain of the web space is not the domain retrieved from pinging, but why?

Thank you!

Comment: `ping` is not a good tool to troubleshoot DNS related problems. You should use `dig` for that or online testing tools like ZoneMaster or DNSViz

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I'll keep it in my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently the parking feature at world4you is called 'multidomain' and I did not know that.